# Retrieving keyboard-layout-independent typed characters from scancodes in Rust

Tags: rust, keyboard, sfml, text-editor, scancodes

I would like to write a low level, fast text editor in Rust. For graphics/windowing, I was planning to use SFML for easy fast cross-compatibility between Windows, macOS, and Linux.

Now, the issue I've come across is when typing characters in a text editor that require the Shift key. SFML, and even other libraries which query native operating system syscalls like [keyboard_query](https://crates.io/crates/keyboard_query) only give you scancodes like "SHIFT and 3 are pressed", now, on my keyboard (a British Macintosh keyboard) I would want that to produce a `£` in the text editor, but an American would want it to produce `#`, and so on and so on for other keyboard layouts.

Is there a reliable cross-platform way to know which character somebody wants to type regardless  of their keyboard layout?

Failing this, is there a way to do it just in macOS? Or will I have to type out a big mapping of what Shift+whatever key produces for every single keyboard layout I want to support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using SFML, then you don't need to convert scancodes.

Instead of watching for [`Event::KeyPressed`](https://docs.rs/sfml/0.15.1/sfml/window/enum.Event.html#variant.KeyPressed), you could just watch for [`Event::TextEntered`](https://docs.rs/sfml/0.15.1/sfml/window/enum.Event.html#variant.TextEntered). That way you get a `unicode: char`, which you can insert directly into your string. The exception being, that you'd still need to watch for [`Event::KeyPressed`](https://docs.rs/sfml/0.15.1/sfml/window/enum.Event.html#variant.KeyPressed), to be able to handle e.g. backspace.

Comment: Brilliant! This is perfect, thank you. Not sure how I missed it in the docs ‍♂️